# Finding the middle number of three random numbers using only max and min functions in JAVA

Tags: java, max, min

I've solved the problem, but I'm wondering if there is a faster way.

Assuming a, b, c are randomly generated numbers, is there a way to find the middle number by only using Math.max and Math.min functions?

```
  med = Math.max(Math.max(Math.min(a,b),Math.min(b,c)),(Math.max(Math.min(b,c),Math.min(a,c))));
```

Thanks a lot, any response would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks you got it - to make it clearer, you can move equivalent parts in separate variables (e.g. Math.min(b,c)) !

Comment: Java, rather than JAVA. This isn't COBOL.

Answer (score 4):

what about the following?

```
min(min(max(a,b), max(b,c)), max(a,c))
```

Comment: Does it work for a=2 b=3 c=1?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input!

I realized it doesn't work when b is the middle number. 
Assuming a is the biggest and c is the smallest. 

min(max(a,b),min(b,c),max(a,c)) would give c.

Comment: @timonik. Now it would work.

Comment: thanks @RohitJain - that's what I actually meant to put down. min of each of the maxes. but I made a mistake.